# Set tickMinStep for altair Axis?

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to set `tickMinStep` for the x-axis in `altair` so that the tick marks occur every two instead of every one.

Here's the documentation where I found the `tickMinStep` parameter.
https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html

This is the example code I'm working with:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies.url

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('IMDB_Rating:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Rating')),
    alt.Y('count()',title="Number of Movies"),
)
```

Both of these ways fail to set `tickMinStep`, and return `SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification`. Any ideas why these fail?

1:

```
chart.configure_axisX(tickMinStep=2)
```

2:

```
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('IMDB_Rating:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Rating', tickMinStep=2)),
    alt.Y('count()',title="Number of Movies"),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method doesn't work because `tickMinStep` is not a configurable option (it is not one of the arguments supported by `alt.AxisConfig`).

The `tickMinStep` option was added to `alt.Axis` in Altiar version 3.0, so trying to use it with older Altair versions will lead to a the schema error you're seeing. Update your Altair installation and your second code block should work without problems.